# Does a Druid in Wild Shape receive the creature's natural attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

I had always assumed this was a no-brainer...the text on Wild Shape clearly says the Druid received the beast's "game statistics" which would seem to indicate you receive the natural attacks... But a player in my game seems to think it only applies to attributes and things like movement or senses.

Is there a definitive answer on this?

Comment: Who is "they" that you are referring to? And what exactly in the text is making you confused? Do you want to know if "game statistics" includes the actions, i.e., the natural attacks?

Comment: "They" being a player in our game. Yes, we want to know if the "game statistics" include the natural attacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wild Shape states

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast

But it seems the confusion is **are actions game statistics?**, or, more generally, **what are game statistics?**

### Actions are game statistics

Page 6 of the Monsters Manual defines what are a monster statistics:

> A monster's statistics, sometimes referred to as its stat block, provide the essential information that you need to run the monster.

Notably, one of the subsections in the Statistics section is Actions, p. 10 and 11, which include the monster attacks.

> The most common actions that a monster will take in combat are melee and ranged attacks. These can be spell attacks or weapon attacks, where the "weapon"  might be a manufactured item or a natural weapon, such as a claw or tail spike.

Therefore, yes, the **attacks from the monster are part of its statistics**, not only movement or senses.

Although there is a notable exception in the Wild Shape feature:

> If the creature has any legendary or lair actions, you can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

The Player's Handbook states that:

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores.

The only actions that the beast may typically have that you would not have while in Wild Shape are explicitly defined as "any legendary or lair actions." All other actions, including regular attacks for the beast, are fair game and would replace your character's typical actions.

Comment: I think I may have just accidentally deleted a comment here, so my apologies for that!

Comment: Oh don't worry, you can't delete comments (you can only flag them for mods to delete). I deleted my comment because after OP's clarification on what exactly is the question, I thought it was worth a detailed answer on it, rather than a brief comment.

Comment: Oh good! I was super confused there for a second.

Comment: @HellSaint I think it is possible to delete someone else's comment merely by flagging it if certain criteria are met; I think it needs to be a short comment in reply to one of your own comments. I think the reasoning behind it is that a comment that meets those criteria is likely to be a "Ok thanks" type message, so are auto-deleted as soon as they are flagged (possibly only if flagged by the person whose comment they are replying to?). I don't know what the exact criteria are, though...

Comment: @NathanS oh yeah. I think if you flag an old enough comment without enough upvotes as No longer needed it gets auto-deleted, and if too many people flag a comment it also gets insta-deleted. But I meant in the sense you can't just go on and delete it yourself. You can flag - and a mod or Community Bot will delete it.